# MySQL 'IN' clause and the returned record set order

Tags: sql, mysql

For example: select * from T where T.id IN(4,78,12,45)

I want the returned record set just order by the position in the 'IN' clause.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do it using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE T.id IN(4,78,12,45)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(T.id,'4,78,12,45');
```

While you do have to duplicate the list, if you're generating the query in code this isn't a huge problem.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about something I didn't know about MySQL!

Comment: For small cases like this, this should be pretty efficient, but if your selection list is large, I would imagine that the temporary table approach is going to be more efficient.

Comment: Woo hoo! That answer got me onto page one of the user list (probably fleetingly - I did it once before in April, went on holiday for two weeks and it's taken over 4 months to get back there!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but what if I need to SHA1 the values of the set?

Comment: The answer is here, if anyone wonders:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135556/uset-find-in-set-my-sql-function-with-hashed-values/23135631?noredirect=1#23135631

Comment: note: if the second parameter of FIND_IN_SET included space character, the result would be random.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can't. SQL doesn't guarantee order unless you use the `ORDER BY` clause, and it can't be tied into the contents of an `IN` statement.

However, if you can build a temporary table that orders the values you're selecting from, you can join on that table and order by it.

For example, you have a temporary table that contains something like the following:

```
id  | order
----+------
4   | 1
78  | 2
12  | 3
45  | 4
```

Then you can order it like this:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T
INNER JOIN temp
ON T.id = temp.id
ORDER BY temp.order ASC
```

Comment: while I like the cleanliness of the solution Paul Dixon offered. This might be easier to understand and may even be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order by the IN clause. You must provide a separate ORDER BY clause. A way of doing this is as follows by building up a case statement in the ORDER BY. It's not pretty though.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    T
WHERE
    T.Id IN(4, 78, 12, 45)
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN T.Id = 4 THEN 1
        WHEN T.Id = 78 THEN 2
        WHEN T.Id = 12 THEN 3
        WHEN T.Id = 45 THEN 4
    END
```