# How to select mysql rows in the order of IN clause

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

For example I have in the table EMPLOYEE:

```
(code, name)
(1, 'Jimmy')
(2, 'Albert')
(3, 'Michelle')
(4, 'Felix' )
```

if you do: (select * from EMPLOYEE) you will get:

```
(1, 'Jimmy')
(2, 'Albert')
(3, 'Michelle')
(4, 'Felix' )
```

if you do: (select * from EMPLOYEE where code in (1,3,2,4) you will get:

```
(1, 'Jimmy')
(2, 'Albert')
(3, 'Michelle')
(4, 'Felix' )
```

How to get it in the order of CSV values in the IN clause, as is?

```
(1, 'Jimmy')
(3, 'Michelle')
(2, 'Albert')
(4, 'Felix' )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort by order of values in a select statement "in" clause in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185029/sort-by-order-of-values-in-a-select-statement-in-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372864/mysql-in-clause-and-the-returned-record-set-order

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399591/sql-sort-order-by-the-order-specified-in-the-query

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245936/order-resultset-based-on-where-in-clause-data

Comment: @JohnFX: I knew one of them had to be mine.  The tagging on them could use updating to be easier to find.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM EMPLOYEE e 
 WHERE e.code in (1,3,2,4) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(e.code, '1,3,2,4')
```

Or use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM EMPLOYEE e 
 WHERE e.code in (1,3,2,4) 
ORDER BY CASE e.code
           WHEN 1 THEN 1 
           WHEN 3 THEN 2
           WHEN 2 THEN 3
           WHEN 4 THEN 4
         END
```

Comment: I'd +1 this if I had the votes right now. Awesome! I'll have to do it when I come back.

Comment: @GolezTrol: "Dirty" is MySQL's continuing lack of analytic support :/

Comment: should it be e.code in the ORDER BY clause?  I'd throw in an edit for review, but I'm a little intimidated by your 73.1k...  ;)

Comment: @J Farray: Corrected. Thx for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to this problem, retaining the order based on your input (CSV) file, is to add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column to your table and order based on that. You probably will never display it as part of your query, but you can order on it to get the original order in your input file, after the import.

Comment: What if the order is different between viewers (IE: you and I)?

Comment: @Ponies, well this assumes a single import of the entire table and a single order based on file input. I am basing my answer on his coupling of the question with a particular CSV (input file) order.

Comment: Other answer assumes perfect knowledge of CSV file. Why use a database any more since you have to reload the CSV file to get the correct order? Obviously you have to record the information somewhere in the database or you already know everything so why even query it? If the order is different between different viewers ??? (does the CSV file change positions). If ordering is that important and actually means something it should be recorded in the DB.