# use FIND_IN_SET my sql function with hashed values

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have the following query:

```
SELECT url, url_hash from pages WHERE url_hash IN (SHA1('URL1'), SHA1('URL2'), SHA1('URL3'))
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(url_hash, "SHA1('URL1'), SHA1('URL2'), SHA1('URL3')")
```

I would to keep the order of the result set the same as the order of the parameters in the IN clause.

I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372864/mysql-in-clause-and-the-returned-record-set-order).

The problem is that mysql doesn't know how to interpret a set of SHA1 functions, if I pass them as strings, they are not evaluated correctly, and if I pass them an an expression (without quotes) I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1582, "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `field()` rather than `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT url, url_hash
from pages 
WHERE url_hash IN (SHA1('URL1'), SHA1('URL2'), SHA1('URL3'))
ORDER BY field(url_hash, SHA1('URL1'), SHA1('URL2'), SHA1('URL3'));
```

Comment: +1 for correctness, but this is going to be horribly, *horribly* inefficient - you are calculating three hashes for every row (in the ORDER clause).

Comment: Actually this is just an example.
I have 30 - 40 urls in each query, the hash is a UNIQUE INDEX.
Better off just selecting 40 rows individually?.
The order of the result set is very crucial to me.

Comment: Non-found records are also very important to me, but those ones I handle programmatically via Python.
If this is truly such an overhead, perhaps i should make the sort programatically us well

Comment: Also, I am using 512mb query cache size, which I plan to increase, and an EC node with SSD drive...